# Setting AES cipher mode for ASP.NET MachineKey from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption-symmetric, form-authentication, machinekey

I try using [ASP.NET FormAuthentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) for my website authentication. I added machineKey element in my web.config so that I can choose what validation and decryption algorithms to use for my authentication. Looking at the [machineKey documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx), I found out that I can choose between these algorithms for the validation:

> [SHA1 | MD5 | 3DES | AES | HMACSHA256 | HMACSHA384 | HMACSHA512 | alg:algorithm_name]

And I can choose between these algorithms for the decryption:

> [Auto | DES | 3DES | AES | alg:algorithm_name]

I notice that when I try to use the AES algorithm (by setting both validation and decryption attribute in machineKey element to "AES"), I can't change its cipher mode (I assume it use CBC as the default [as the documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode(v=vs.110).aspx)). I want to use AES algorithm with different cipher mode here. So just setting the attributes' value to "AES" doesn't solve my problem. The machineKey documentation says this for the `alg:algorithm_name`:

> alg:algorithm_name  Specifies that ASP.NET uses a custom algorithm to encrypt and decrypt data. The encryption algorithm must be defined in a class that derives from SymmetricAlgorithm. ASP.NET calls the SymmetricAlgorithm.Create method and passes in the name of the algorithm that is specified here.

Reading this I assume that it is possible to reference a custom algorithm made with `SymmetricAlgorithm.Create` method here. And since [SymmetricAlgorithm class has a "mode" property which can be used for getting and setting the cipher mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.100).aspx), I guess this can solve my problem.

Now my problem is I don't know how to reference my custom algorithm (which is AES but using other cipher mode, e.g. ECB mode) into the machineKey element in the web.config. I am trying to find other documentation, with no luck. Is there any way to set the validation and decryption attribute of the machineKey element in web.config so that it use my custom algorithm? Or is there any other way so that I can use my custom algorithm for the FormAuthentication's validation and decryption?